# Login to Weibo using OAuth 2.0 from iOS app?

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, weibo

I'm trying to login to Sina Weibo from my iOS app using OAuth 2.0. I got the official Sina Weibo SDK from [here](https://github.com/mobileresearch/weibo_ios_sdk_sso-oauth) and official documentation from [here](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/%E7%A7%BB%E5%8A%A8%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8SSO%E6%8E%88%E6%9D%83).

When I import the SDK and creates an instance it asks for appRedirectURI.

```
SinaWeibo *sinaWeibo = [[SinaWeibo alloc] initWithAppKey:kAppKey appSecret:kAppSecret appRedirectURI:kAppRedirectURI andDelegate:self];
```

I want to know why we need RedirectURI in iOS app, I know it is required in Android apps but I think it is not required in iOS apps.

Can someone please explain me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did not you try the wrapper class from [here](https://github.com/mobileresearch/weibo_ios_sdk_sso-oauth), which make things easy?